# Loop through multipage xml file in php?

Tags: php, xml

Hi all i'm trying to loop through a multipage xml file using a counter to test at the moment, but i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong for it to be an endless page load:

```
$counter = 1;
while ($xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents("http://www.gog.com/games/feed?format=xml&page=$counter")))
{
    $counter++;
    echo $counter;
}
```

They sadly don't have a total page number counter, so I thought I would test going over it until it fails to reach it (gives 404 if it tries a page that doesn't exist).

I thought I could use a simple while (this works) loop to do it, but it appears not.

Comment: are you getting any error messages?

Comment: No, it just gives me a blank page.

Comment: ok got the problem. The xml feed you are trying to load always sends a valid xml for any page number. You have to verify if there is data and exit the loop.\

Comment: What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this

```
$counter = 1;
$finished = false;
while (!$finished)
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents("http://www.gog.com/games/feed?format=xml&page=$counter"));
    $counter++;
    echo $counter;
    if (count($xml->products->product) < 1){ //check if we have products
        $finished = true; //We hit a blank page
    }
}
```

Note: I don't have access to PHP now, writing from my mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

You've most likely run into a ban because of your endless requesting URL after URL because your loop-exiting condition did never break the loop.

Here is a little different but working example:

```
$urlMask = 'http://www.gog.com/games/feed?format=xml&page=%d';

$page = 0;
do {
    $url = sprintf($urlMask, $page++);
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
    if (!$xml) {
        printf("Error: Failed to open URL '%s'\n", $url);
        break; // problems loading url.
    }

    $path  = '/catalogue/products/product';
    $count = count($xml->xpath($path));
    printf("Page #%d: %d product(s)\n", $page, $count);

} while ($count > 0);
```

The important part here is next to error handling of opening the document you should do a positive check that there are actually products. In this example I use the product count to exit the loop if there ain't any more products.

Here the exemplary output:

```
Page #1: 62 product(s)
Page #2: 62 product(s)
Page #3: 63 product(s)
Page #4: 65 product(s)
Page #5: 54 product(s)
Page #6: 61 product(s)
Page #7: 70 product(s)
Page #8: 66 product(s)
Page #9: 67 product(s)
Page #10: 82 product(s)
Page #11: 74 product(s)
Page #12: 75 product(s)
Page #13: 65 product(s)
Page #14: 0 product(s)
```

Lesson to learn: Introduce a sanity-check as well, like if you start to develop, exist after two loops just to check if things work. Then do a limit on 20 pages because you've already found out there ain't more than 13 normally so such mistakes aren't hurting. My example still have this problem, there is no sanity check in it. In case the XML is not as expected, this still can cause problems.

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
$counter = 1;
while (true)
  $file = fopen ("http://www.gog.com/games/feed?format=xml&page=" . $counter, "r");
  if (!$file) break;
  $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
  fclose($file);
  $counter++;
  // Do your xml stuff here
}
```

Comment: That also gives me a blank page.

Comment: Could you place error_reporting(E_ALL); at the top of your code and give the error?

Comment: Seems it's giving my server a 503 error checking error logs, but it's up in my browser so I think I've been blocked, will have to email them, damn.